# Swift: unit test page-jump

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Notification", bundle: Bundle.main)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! Notification
 vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
 self.present(vc, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

I want to test that if the current page will navigate to 'Notification' page, I have no idea that how to test it. In Objective-C, we can use OCMock to test. Do you guys have some good methods?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you need to use UITest not UnitTest for that purpose.

Hope this should help.
Wish you all the best.